# Open a file with a double click

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now files are opened with one click.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, search for "open mode" and change the setting for "Workbench > List: Open Mode" to `doubleClick`:

[image: Open Mode settings in VS Code]

Comment: works great @Ocaso Protal